# Moment of inertia of a rotating black hole

Tags: black-holes, angular-momentum, moment-of-inertia, kerr-metric

The moment of inertia of a massive object about a given axis describes how its mass is distributed about that axis. I understand that a rotating black hole of a given mass and angular velocity possesses angular momentum, and one would think that it therefore possesses a certain moment of inertia about its axis of rotation. My question is this: can knowledge of that moment of inertia tell us anything about how the black hole's mass is distributed about its axis of rotation?

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/310881/

Comment: thanks for the reference, I did find it earlier this week, but it did not reveal to me whether the value for the moment of inertia could be understood in terms of a spatial distribution of mass. Also, the results were expressed in units in which c and G were set to 1, which makes those results difficult for me to interpret.

Answer (score 1):

1; Are you asking regarding a specific "point" or location on the event horizon, inside the event horizon, or in a general angular region relative to the axis of rotation? To me, it seems you are wrestling with defining the "membrane" of the event horizon, which I believe would be impossible, as that is the region of ultimate flux as can be located by mankind, currently.
2;Were "1" defined, I think the logical answer is yes, but "1" seems to be in constant flux, and undefinable to a quantifiable  point. Possibly by general latitudes/longitudes, but even then the flux as mass converts and or is accrued would be changing too voluminously to render anything more than speculative generalizations. 
In my opinions....

Comment: Sorry, I meant outside the event horizon. I do not understand your other comments.