# What percent of the Black Hole energy is in the gravitational field significantly outside the event horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, energy, gravity, black-holes, event-horizon

This question is sparked with [an answer to another one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/445853/). We know that fields have mass-energy and gravitational field is no exception, some share of BH mass should be contributed by its gravitational field.

Answer (score 1):

The energy in a gravitational field cannot be localized in GR.  The Newtonian expression for the energy density of the gravitational field is proportional to $g^2$, where $g$ is the gravitational field, but the equivalence principle tell us that $g$ is not observable in GR. For example, we can make $g=0$ at any point we like, simply by adopting an inertial frame of reference. There is a detailed discussion of this sort of thing in Wald, section 11.2. When we talk about the mass of a black hole, we're talking about some quantity such as its ADM mass, which is essentially the mass measured by a distant observer.

Comment: A more recent thinking is that energy (or rather, energy–momentum) in GR  is *properly* quasi-local, i.e. associated with a closed 2-surface. For an overview see [lrr-2009-4](https://doi.org/10.12942/lrr-2009-4). With that in mind, OP's question sort of makes sense.

Comment: This does not answer the question :(

Comment: @Anixx: The answer to the question is that there is no answer to the question.

Comment: @A.V.S.: That sounds interesting. How about writing up an answer along those lines?